# The css style is not the same in development environment and distribution environment

Tags: webpack, vue.js

My Vue.js project, the css style is not the same in development environment and distribution environment.

This is the development environment effect:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This is the distribution environment effect:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why there is this difference between them?

This is my `webpack.prod.conf` code, I am not sure whether is because of my webpack configuration:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const GenerateAssetPlugin = require('generate-asset-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')


const env = require('../config/prod.env')

const createServerConfig = function(compilation){
  let cfgJson={ApiUrl:"http://103.20.12.76:8000"};
  return JSON.stringify(cfgJson);
}

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    // new UglifyJsPlugin({
    //   uglifyOptions: {
    //     compress: {
    //       warnings: false
    //     }
    //   },
    //   sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
    //   parallel: true
    // }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
        ecma:8,
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      }
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`, 
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),

//          from:path.join(__dirname, "static", "js"),
        filename: 'static/js/server_config.json',
        fn: (compilation, cb) => {
            cb(null, createServerConfig(compilation));
        },
        extraFiles: []
    }),

//          from:path.join(__dirname, "static", "js"),
        filename: 'static/js/server_config.json',
        fn: (compilation, cb) => {
            cb(null, createServerConfig(compilation));
        },
        extraFiles: []
    })
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

---

**EDIT-1**

I find this detail:

In my distribution page, I find the `width: 25%`;

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

if I uncheck it, the style will become normal.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

However, if I in my local development environment, I find if I do not uncheck the `width: 25%`, there is still works fine. so maybe this is not relative to the `ivu-col-6`.

---

**EDIT-2**

I put the `computed` panel in there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem of order of CSS definition. The development and production CSS definition order might be different. Reference link: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/migrating.html#style-injection.

You need to make use of CSS specificity to fix the issues.

For example

```
// dmeo.html
<span class='Color'>Colored Text</span>

// demo.css
.Color {
   color: blue;
}

.Color {
   color: red;
}
```

The above definition will result is `color: red`.

You can alter the result by increasing the specificity of the first rule.

```
// dmeo.html
<span class='Color'>Colored Text</span>

// demo.css
span.Color {
   color: blue;
}

.Color {
   color: red;
}
```

You can check the CSS specificity using https://specificity.keegan.st/.

Comment: Specific what to do, and should I provide what more code in there?

Comment: You can read up on CSS specificity at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [cssspecificity.com](http://cssspecificity.com/). You should write your selectors such that they are not dependent on their ordering – if the rules were rearranged, would it still look correct?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 You should check your active CSS rules on the production version of your elements. Then you need to fix those rules by increasing the CSS specificity of the rule you want.

Comment: @MortyChoi See my EDIT-1, can you find something from this?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 You can use the `computed` tab to see the CSS order read by the browser and which one got overridden.

Answer (score 0):

1. check whether in your components' `<style>` label, you add the `scoped`.
2. if you use 3th UI lib like `element-ui`, check whether the `App` import is after the 3th UI lib, the order is care about.

   ```
   import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css';
   ...
   import App from './App';
   ```

3.in your `webpack.prod.conf.js`, check whether the `cssProcessorOptions` have `safe: true`:

```
   new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
     cssProcessorOptions: {
       safe: true
     }
   }),
```

detail in [GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/614).